Windows Media player classic. Auto start 5 second video before playing anything else
I'm using media player classic. And I want to know how to start a 5-second video to play before playing the main video I selected. Basically I have a home theater setup. I want the malco movie theaters intro to play before any movie I start playing. Is there a way to automatically do this without using a playlist?
Thanks

Probably not the best solution but I'd just stitch the INTRO with the MOVIE file. It can be done without re-encoding if the format matches (ie.: you prepare the intro movie in the same format/encoding). This way, you are 100% sure the intro plays and there is no awkward skips or anything.

You could write a batch script that takes one argument, the name of the main movie, The first thing the script would do is call a video player with the 5 sec logo, then play the file sent in the command line. You would have to write that script.
